# Setting multiple CallableStatement variables with nested SQL queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm confused how to set a `CallableStatement` variable with nested queries. Is it based on which is first in the string? Or first in the execution plan?

```
final String sql =
        "update employees\n" +
        "set in_store = ?\n" +                // Is this the first variable?
        "where employee_id = (\n" +
        "    select es.employee_id\n" +
        "    from employee_store as es\n" +
        "    inner join stores as s on s.store_id = es.store_id\n" +
        "    where s.store_id = ?\n" +        // Or is this the first variable?
        ");";

final CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
stmt.setBoolean(1, inStore);
stmt.setInt(2, storeId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter values of `PreparedStatement` are substituted by the position in the query rather than by execution plan. For your query, in_store will be first param and store_id will be second.

You can also see the generated query by doing `System.out.pringln(stmt)`.